# What is the report called that tells you whether a business venture is worth pursuing?

Tags: planning, resource-planning, business-case, business-improvement

This report would be distinct from a market research report which helps a business understand something central or auxiliary component of their existing business. I'm referring to a report that helps individuals or businesses decide whether a completely new venture is worth pursuing; what the market is like for your product, what it's worth, etc.

Comment: Hi Karen, welcome. How are you defining "worth pursuing"? Do you have an example of such file you could share its structure to help us visualize what you mean?

Comment: I wish I had an example. No, I'm referring to more of a research report that one undertakes before beginning anything in the business—no building, no permits, product, nothing. Reading this report I want to get an idea of the market. Is there a market for my product? And what does it look like? Potential target market? Pricing? Etc.

Comment: Is it financially worth pursuing....

Comment: [Business plan](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/247574)?

Comment: A business plan is "a document that tells what you plan to do and how you plan to do it". The document I'm trying to pinpoint would come before a business plan, mayyybe alongside one, but would answer the question, should I do anything at all? No, the market is too saturated, or there's is no demand for my product, or yes, but what the market is demanding, I would have to make this or that modification. Honestly I have no idea what such a document would tell me. I have never seen it. If there were such a document, it would be called the "Market Pulse Research".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean a [Business Feasibility Plan](https://bizfluent.com/how-2342194-create-feasibility-business-plan.html).